# iphone Table View Cell For Row not being called when Rows For Section is returning > 0

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Using table views in a view controller that is being used as sub views to another controller.  They are displaying fine when first created, etc.  Selections are working fine, etc.

But when trying to change the display items in the table, the datasource array is being changed and a reload is done on the main thread.  The Rows in Section is being called properly with the correct size of the array being returned, etc.  BUT cell for row is not being called.

Here is the sub view setup...

```
    [self addChildViewController : SQLTableNames];
    [self.view addSubview : SQLTableNames.view];
    [SQLTableNames didMoveToParentViewController : self];
```

Where SQLTableNames is a ViewController with tableview(s) in them

have tried everything, delayed reload, reload on main, etc.  Delayed from the main view controller, delayed in the sub view controller, etc.

It's seems like the return from rows in section is simply being ignored.......

Have tried set need display, and Reload Rows at Index Paths.  None of these will call the Cell for Row to repaint the table.

All the delegates are fine.  It display's once fine and then can't change the table display.

Answer (score 0):

If you called [self.tableView beginUpdates] before your inserts, ensure that you call

```
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

after.